# trying to use igaster/laravel-theme but can't get it to work

Tags: laravel

I am using this package to introduce themes to my app, https://github.com/igaster/laravel-theme I made a theme named default inside resources/views and put my views inside. Inside my controller method where I call the view, before I call the view I did

```
Theme::set('default');
return view('index');
```

when I enter that specific route, I get:

> InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [index] not found.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know this package, but going purely on that error. Do you have a view called index.blade.php ?

Comment: Yes i have index.blade.php